# Are all normal operators diagonalized? Autoadjoint

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, diagonalization, adjoint-operators, orthogonal-matrices

My teacher has given us that

> If $f$ is normal then it is diagonalizable

The thing is that I've studied all 4 operators, orthogonal, unitary, symmetric and self-adjoint operators and I've been told that all of them are normal operators, since all satisfy that $ff^{*}=f^{*}f$. But I have also been told that the orthogonal operators, which are the ones that satisfy $f^{*}=f^{-1}$ (in the real plane) and are not *always* diagonalizable. So what's going on here? Is it that the theorem is "if $f$ is normal and complex then it is diagonalizable"? Or what is going on so that both statement don't correlate?

Comment: They're all diagonalizable over $\Bbb{C}$, but normal real matrices with non-real eigenvalues are not diagonalizable over $\Bbb{R}$.

Comment: And beware that the adjoint $f^*$ here means for the *hermitian* inner product. A complex *non-real* symmetric matrix is *not self-adjoint* (i.e. not equal to its [transjugate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_transpose)), and generally not normal.

Answer (score 1):

Consider
$$O=\begin{pmatrix}
\cos\theta&-\sin\theta\\
\sin\theta&\cos\theta
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Then $O^t O = O^* O = O O^* = O O^t = \mathbf{1}$.  So $O$ is normal.
$$
O
\begin{pmatrix}
1\\
i
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
e^{-i\theta}\\
i e^{-i\theta}
\end{pmatrix}
= e^{-i\theta}
\begin{pmatrix}
1\\
i
\end{pmatrix}
$$

$$
O
\begin{pmatrix}
1\\
-i
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
e^{i\theta}\\
-i e^{i\theta}
\end{pmatrix}
= e^{i\theta}
\begin{pmatrix}
1\\
-i
\end{pmatrix}
$$
The eigenvalues $e^{i\theta}, e^{-i\theta}$ are non-real (except for $\theta\in\{0,\pi\}$) and associated eigenvectors have non-real entries.  $O$ is not diagonalizable over $\Bbb{R}$.  For the cases $\theta=0$ or $\theta=\pi$, $O=\pm \mathbf{1}$ so all vectors (including real-valued vectors) are eigenvectors for it.

Comment: what does has to do with my question at all?

Comment: @Aley20:  you asked how an operator can both be diagonalizable and not diagonalizable.  I showed an example that is diagonalizable over $\Bbb{C}$, but not $\Bbb{R}$.

Comment: reorganised my doubts into a brand new question, I thought it would be easier since I summarised my doubts better, appreciate your comments, you may check it if you want https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4685037/interesting-questions-about-normal-operators